# html simple dom get date-time vaule

Tags: html, twitter, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the timestamp of date-time in this html.

```
<span class="js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp"
    data-time="1401528672"
    data-long-form="true">
    15h
  </span>
```

Using **html simple dom** how would I get the value "1401528672" from this html. Yes the value/timestamp will change so I need to get value of [date-time] in the html.

Any ideas?

```
include('simpleHtmlDom/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("https://twitter.com/$user");
//not working
$date = $html->find('span[data-time]->attribute()', 0);
print_r($date);
exit;
```

Comment: Is the value in `data-time` the number of seconds after epoch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
include('simpleHtmlDom/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html('<span class="js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp"
    data-time="1401528672"
    data-long-form="true">
    15h
  </span>');
$data = $html->find('span', 0);

echo $data->attr['data-time'];
```

@Papa De Beau: I tried the above code using simplehtmldom and it worked :)

Comment: wild, this actually goes recursive. never ending.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau Strange!! I tried it using simplehtmldom version 1.5

Comment: at some point I need this to get all html. $html = file_get_html("https://twitter.com/$user");

Comment: In short, I am trying to get the date of the latest tweet of a users. But I need the time stamp because I don't want to display "1 min ago" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using plain Html,

```
// Create a DOM object from a string
$html = str_get_html('<span class="js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp"
    data-time="1401528672"
    data-long-form="true">
    15h
  </span>');

//Now get the reference to Span object
$data = $html->find('span', 0);

//Now get the attribute value 
echo $data->attr['data-time'];
```

If you have option of using JavaScript and have access to span element source code, you can use below solution,

If you give your span element some id attribute, say span1, than you can use getAttribute() method to get the information you want.. see below code

```
<span class="js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp" id='span1'
    data-time="1401528672"
    data-long-form="true">
    15h
</span>

<!-- now retrieve the value of date-time any where else -->

var element = document.getElementById('span1');
var dateTimeVal = element.getAttribute("data-time");
```

Hope it works..

[See full example here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_data)

Comment: It's not my code, I am only abstracting it. It's actually from twitter.com

Comment: Well in that case can you iterate through js-short-timestamp or js-relative-timestamp class to get the data-time ? see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ndpfd/

Comment: @Amit Papa De Beau wants it using simple html dom not by javascript

Comment: @Gunaseelan yes I understood his case and by the time I finished typing my answer 'Mahavir Munot' already posted somewhat similar answer. So I decided to discard mine.. Not deleting the answer since it can be useful for someone else in future. Let the community decide its future.. . ..

Comment: @Amit Ok. Please update your answer since I need to remove the downvote